# export excel file from dataset in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have data in sql server i want to export to data with asp.net C#

Answer (score 0):

[This example](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=MSOffice&file=ExtractToExcel2.cs) shows how to extract data from SQL Server into Excel spreadsheet using a single dataset, and two distinct DataAdapters.

```
  // fill data from SQL
  var ConnSql= new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnStringSql);

  var da1 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
  da1.SelectCommand=  new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlSelect);
  da1.SelectCommand.Connection= ConnSql;

  var ds1 = new System.Data.DataSet();
  da1.Fill(ds1, "Extracto");

  // need to update the rows so the DA does the insert...
  foreach (System.Data.DataRow r in ds1.Tables[0].Rows) { 
    r["Extracted"]= System.DateTime.Now; // update one column in each row
  }

  // insert into Excel
  var ConnExcel= new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConnStringExcel);
  var da2 = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();

  da2.UpdateCommand= new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sqlInsert);
  da2.UpdateCommand.Connection= ConnExcel;

  da2.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@ProductId", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer, 4, "ProductId");
    ..etc..

  da2.Update(ds1, "Extracto");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also export it in a CSV file separated by comma "," or other separators. For this you have to use StreamWriter object for writing text file and looping through the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Spreadsheetgear is a really great tool for this type of thing - very fast and easy to use. I only wish they had a less expensive version, at just under $1000 its pricey, but seems to do all that it is advertised to.

Lets you not only export the data, but formats, colors, fonts and graphs too.